# Linux command line. Move all files and directories in directory, except some files and directories

Tags: command-line, files, directory, move

I have a folder `A` which has files and directories, I want to move all those files and directories to another folder `B`, except `file`, `file2`, `directory`, and `directory2`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
mv A/^(file|directory)(|2)(D) B/
```

(the `(D)` to include *dot* (hidden) files).

With `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob failglob
mv A/!(@(file|directory)?(2)) B/
```

With `ksh93`

```
(FIGNORE='@(.|..|@(file|directory)?(2))'; mv A/* B)
```

Comment: I don't even want to think about how much time you must have spent in each shell to learn this! Great answer!

Answer (score 10):

what i usually do

```
cd A
ls > a
```

(assuming you have no 'a' file).

```
vi a
```

remove whatever file or directory to be kept in place.

```
mv $(<a) B
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm thinking some of the experts maybe have some command/"one liner" which is less of a hassle.

Comment: It depends, if I have to do it once (my solution) or many time @Falko's solution.

Comment: @somethingSomething This solution allows you to check what you are about to do before you do it. Don't underestimate that.

Comment: @Ben, beware though that you have to check that the file names don't contain blank or wildcards or don't start with `-`. You won't be able to spot file names that contain newline characters and it will omit hidden files.

Comment: @Ben I see your point.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, 1) if you want to include hidden files just use `ls -a` instead. 2) If you have filenames containing newlines, tabs or nonprintable characters you have bigger problems, and the question should be how to identify and get rid of them.

Comment: This can be dangerous for one more reason: if `ls` is an alias to `ls -F` (which is common when not using colors),  source paths can have leading `/`, which can have severe side effects - see "Warning" and "Trailing slashes" in `info mv` (or `pinfo mv`, but not in `man mv`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `find` with excluded expressions:

```bsh
find . ! -name . -prune ! -path ./file \
                        ! -path ./file2 \
                        ! -path ./directory \
                        ! -path ./directory2 \
     -exec mv {} your_destination \;
```

This solution is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612157/how-to-use-mv-command-to-move-files-except-those-in-a-specific-directory).

Comment: I get: find: unknown predicate `-E' if I copy and paste your solution, and modify "your_destination" accordingly.

Comment: @somethingSomething: I guess you can drop the ```-E``` option. But there might be differences between our systems, since I'm currently on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | egrep -v '(file|file2|directory|directory2)' | xargs -i mv {} ../B/
```

Answer (score 1):

If `./A` and `./B` are on the same filesystem *and* if these files do not already exist in `./B`:

```
file file2 directory directory2
```

...then this operation should just be atomic:

```
cd ./A; mv * ../B
for mv in file file2 directory directory2
do mv ../B/"$mv" .
done
```

If they are not, then there are *at least* 8 additional cross-device copies done with the above set of commands.

Comment: Not aware of any shell which guarantees this to truly be atomic. However it should be "really really fast" if its on the same fs. EDIT - that is each mv may be atomic if on the same fs but the entire mv is not atomic

Comment: @Brandin - the shell has no involvement in whether or not that is an atomic operation or not. `mv` `unlinks` and `renames` when not crossing devs - it just affects dentries, basically, as i understand it. But the shell doesnt get into that.

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo mv (source folder name) A     B(destination foldername)

ex:
create empty dir some sub folder a
1)sudo mkdir -p A/{b/{a,b,c},c,d}

2)ls A/

b c d

3) sudo mkdir B

5)sudo mv a(folder) b(folder)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bash array to store which ones you want to skip and then use the `containsElement` function demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574392/1691280):

```sh
$ skiplist=(file file2 directory directory2)
$ for f in *; do if containsElement "$f" "${skiplist[@]}"; then continue; fi;
mv -v "$f" B; done
```