# Moving only files, not directories?

Tags: shell, find, wildcards, mv

I want to move all the files, but not the folders, inside a folder to another directory.

I have been using this command:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} destination_folder \;`

But now I want to move all the files except the ones that start with "exe_", so I tried:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv !(exe_*) part1a_si_atom-exp001 \;`

But now it also moves directories. What can I do?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154525/linux-command-line-move-all-files-and-directories-in-directory-except-some-fil?rq=1

Comment: Is this just inconsistent use of terminology or is there a difference for you between folders and directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!(exe_*)` is getting interpreted by your shell and expanded before your find command is even run.  Instead, try the `-name` flag to find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name 'exe_*' -exec mv {} destination_folder \;
```

I also recommend using `+` instead of `;` as the terminator for your `-exec` command to reduce overhead.